# Testing a method with Akka Actor parameters

Tags: testing, akka, actor

I have a task, which I need to test. This task takes some actors as parameters, so I created a test with a `TestActor` as follows:

Few questions: 
1. Is it a normal practice to create `ActorSystem` for test purposes?
2. The code doesn't end. I have tried to

```
val system = ActorSystem("TestRoutingSystem")
val actorRef = system.actorOf(Props(new TestActor), name = "testActor")


var poisonReceived = false
var workReceived = 0
class TestActor extends Actor with Logging {
  def receive = {
    case msg: WorkerMessage =>
      workReceived += 1
    case x: Boolean => {
      poisonReceived = true
    }
  }
}

val t = new java.util.Timer()
val task = new TestTask(...)
task.run()
t.schedule(task, 10, 10)
system.shutdown()



Thread.sleep(150)
println(poisonReceived )
println(workReceived)
```

Comment: For testing purposes is highly recommended to use akka-testkit module http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html

Comment: btw, @nafr I am not testing an actor. I am testing another method which takes Actor as parameters.

Comment: What does it mean "The code doesn't end"? How you run test(junit, scalatest)?

Comment: @zella i figured that the background `Timer` thread `t` was running as it was not cancelled. This was a test code although I hadn't plugged it into a test framework, since I discovered it continuing forever.

Answer (score 1):

As @nafr said, it's better to use `akka-testkit`

I'm not familiar with scalatest, so I write example in junit style. For example we should test some class, that send two messages to actor:

```
  class TimerTask(actorRef: ActorRef) {

    def run(): Unit = {
      actorRef ! "some msg"
      actorRef ! "some other msg"
    }
  }
```

Complete test will look like this:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.testkit.{TestKit, TestProbe}
import org.junit.{After, Before, Test}

class TestExample {

  protected implicit var system: ActorSystem = _

  @Before
  def setup(): Unit = {
    system = ActorSystem.create("test")
  }

  @After
  def tearDown(): Unit = {
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
  }

  @Test
  def example(): Unit = {
    val testProbe = TestProbe()

    val source = new TimerTask(testProbe.ref)

    source.run()

    testProbe.expectMsg("some msg")
    testProbe.expectMsg("some other msg")
  }
}
```

So answers on your question:
1) It's the only true way to test something, where actors participate
2) Use `TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)`